# Restrict a number to upper/lower bounds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a built-in way or a more elegant way of restricting a number *num* to upper/lower bounds in Ruby or in Rails?

e.g. something like:

```
def number_bounded (num, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  return lower_bound if num < lower_bound
  return upper_bound if num > upper_bound
  num
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a clever way to do it:

```
[lower_bound, num, upper_bound].sort[1]
```

But that's not very readable. If you only need to do it once, I would just do

```
num < lower_bound ? lower_bound : (num > upper_bound ? upper_bound : num)
```

or if you need it multiple times, monkey-patch the Comparable module:

```
module Comparable
  def bound(range)
     return range.first if self < range.first
     return range.last if self > range.last
     self
  end
end
```

so you can use it like

```
num.bound(lower_bound..upper_bound)
```

You could also just require [ruby facets](http://facets.rubyforge.org/apidoc/index.html), which adds a method `clip` that does just this.

Comment: Thanks, I might go the Ruby Facets route.

Answer (score 12):

You can use min and max to make the code more concise:

```
number_bounded = [lower_bound, [upper_bound, num].min].max
```

Comment: This is possibly the faster way to do it than the sort() version below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Range

  def clip(n)
    if cover?(n)
      n
    elsif n < min
      min
    else
      max
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is clamp: https://ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp

```
12.clamp(0, 100)         #=> 12
523.clamp(0, 100)        #=> 100
-3.123.clamp(0, 100)     #=> 0

'd'.clamp('a', 'f')      #=> 'd'
'z'.clamp('a', 'f')      #=> 'f'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mentioning Rails, I'll mention how to do this with a validation.

```
validates_inclusion_of :the_column, :in => 5..10
```

That won't auto-adjust the number, of course.